# send raw image or binary data directly to the other application

Tags: android, image

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to send raw data to the other application? Example: taking pictures from a custom camera and send to other application. I observe that using intent is just only sending data which is already saved to storage, but i want that let the 2nd application decided either they save the image or discard. Just like in the tutorial of on how to make custom camera but in that instance, only one application running and only startActivityForResult and the listener which is onResultActivity. In my case, I want that from my custom camera, pass the raw data to the other application and let the other application manage the raw image receive. I call this raw image because this image is in the buffer and not on the storage. Is that possible to pass the raw image/data to other application?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to save the file and pass the URI to the file via an Intent.

```
        Uri image = Uri.parse(fileName);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, image);
            myIntent.setType("image/*");
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Open Image");
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: OP wants to send data to *other application*, not other activity.

Comment: using uri.parse is just pulling the data from the storage right? so it means, it is already save to storage and uri pulled the data via parsing the filename...that is not what i want, I want is like this, after capturing the image from the camera, the raw data or image from the capture camera stored in the buffer was directly send to the other application and the other application have an option they they want to save or discard. my application is a camera have an option that My Tracks can use the camera but after taking images, it will not return back to My Tracks.

Comment: and to go back to My Tracks, i added startResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent) and  code is finish(); now its working but the problem is the image was not set to My Tracks and return to black image or zero(0) bytes.

Comment: but i will try this suggestion.

Comment: You can not send the raw image file in this way. You would need to save it temporarily and then send the filename to the other application as I have described.

Comment: i'd try but the it return that "no apps can perform this action" but before opening the camera, the application i use is My Tracks and from My Tracks i click the camera icon and now the camera open. Taking picture but instead that viewing the image, it returns to this dialog "no apps can perform this action".

Comment: i'd change the "Open Image" to "com.google.android.apps.mytracks" but the phone says that unable to find the application to perform this action

Comment: can i ask if you have an idea what class of My Tracks that hold the image or an imageViewer

Comment: I updated the code to include the "settype" which you might also need.

Comment: The premise of this answer is mistaken - **there is no requirement to save the data as file**, except where that is the only way in which a particular target application is willing to accept it.